# App just shows a black screen

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to make a multiview application.  I started by creating an 'empty application' as I thought this would be easiest.  I have 3 .xib files, the first being MainView.xib which has a view controller which is linked to my switch class, and has a tool bar to switch between the two views, and I have selected this .xib to be 'main interface' which I thought meant that should be loaded first.  My other blue are RedView.xib and BlueView.xib.

I've heard this method in AppDelegate.m can cause some problems, here is mine...

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    //add SwitchClasses view to the main window
    [window addSubview:switchObject.view]; 
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

I don't know whether I have missed something because I started with an empty application, or if I've messed something up along the way.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you alloc init an instance of your switch class? Also, this is not the way to do it any more. You should have window.rootViewController = switchObject;

Comment: My advice would be to just start over with Xcode's "Single View" application, see how that works, and take it from there.

Comment: //What happens when the app is loaded
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    switchObject = [[SwitchClass alloc] init];
    //add SwitchClasses view to the main window
    window.rootViewController = switchObject;
}

This is my new method, the same thing happens...
As regards to using a single view application, is this okay?  Or is it correct to do it using an empty one?

Comment: You should use initWithNibName:bundle:, and pass it the name of the nib file where you created the view. It's fine to start with an empty template, you're just recreating what Apple does in their single view template. You should have a look at one so you can see what's in there. You need to create the window too. Have you done that?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
window.rootViewController = switchObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have given reference from XIB view to the ViewController for both the Views you are using in TabBar. then try the following.

```
switchObject = [[[switchObject alloc] initWithNibName:@"switchObjectXib" bundle:nil] autorelease];
window.rootViewController = switchObject;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

hope this will help you.